# python regex: search for variable content inside javascript function

Tags: python, regex

I have a javascript string like given below

```
function() {window.__WML_REDUX_INITIAL_STATE__ = {"uuid":null,"isMobile":false,"isBot":false,"isAdsEnabled":true};}
```

I have to get contents of `__WML_REDUX_INITIAL_STAET__ =` whose content is json data so that I could parse the json further.

I'm, using following regex pattern

```
wml_redux_initial_state = re.findall('__WML_REDUX_INITIAL_STATE__ = (.*?);\s*$', redux, re.M)
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how specific your regex needs to be, but your current one isn't working because of the `}` after the `;`....this works:

```
re.search(r'__WML_REDUX_INITIAL_STATE__ = (.*?);}\s*$', redux, re.M)
```

Comment: but this search includes `__WML_REDUX_INITIAL_STATE__`  string too. I only want content within it.

Comment: Thanks, I used your regex string in `findall` and it's working

Comment: in my `re.search` it returns a `match` object which contains what you're looking for in the first group. You could access it by `match.group(1)`.